# Serializable class is not shown in custom inspector

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, serialization, editor

I am creating custom inspector for my ScriptableObjects in unity, and I have noticed that my Serializable class's properties aren't displayed

I have created a simple script to hold a character data, and one of it fields is a Serializable class. If I don't use custom inspector I can see the class in the inspector, but if I try to make one it automatically just displayes the field name in foldout view, and when I unfold it, it is empty.

My Class:

```
using UnityEngine;
[System.Serializable]
public class Skills
{
    [SerializeField, Tooltip("This character agility level")]
    private byte agility, strength;

}
```

My Data ScriptableObject:

```
using UnityEngine;
using Weapons.ScriptableObjects;
namespace Characters.ScriptableObjects
{
     [CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New Character", menuName 
"Characters/Soldier")]
    public class SoldierData : CharacterData
    {
        public Weapon weapon;
        public float life = 100;
        public bool autoAttack = true;
        public Skills skills = new Skills();
    }
}
```

And finally my custom editor:

```
using UnityEditor;
namespace Characters.CustomEditors
{
    [CustomEditor(typeof(ScriptableObjects.SoldierData))]
    public class SoldierEditor : CharacterEditor
    {
        private SerializedProperty life, autoAttack, skills, weapon;
        private bool showBaseProperties = true, showWeaponProperties = false;

        private new void OnEnable()
        {
            base.OnEnable();
            life = serializedObject.FindProperty("life");
            autoAttack = serializedObject.FindProperty("autoAttack");
            skills = serializedObject.FindProperty("skills");
            weapon = serializedObject.FindProperty("weapon");
        }
        public override void OnInspectorGUI()
        {
            showBaseProperties = EditorGUILayout.Foldout(showBaseProperties, "Basic settings:");
            if (showBaseProperties)
            {
                base.OnInspectorGUI();
            }
            serializedObject.Update();
            showWeaponProperties = EditorGUILayout.Foldout(showWeaponProperties, "Weapon settings");
            if (showWeaponProperties)
            {
                EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(autoAttack);
                EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(life);
            }
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(skills);
            serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to see my Skills class's properties in the custom inspector

Answer (score 1):

It works for me

My Class:

```
[Serializable]
public class Skills
{
    [SerializeField]
    public byte[] m_Arr;
}
```

My Data ScriptableObject:

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New Character", menuName =
"Characters/Soldier")]
public class SoldierData : ScriptableObject
{
    //public Weapon weapon;
    public float life = 100;
    public bool autoAttack = true;
    public Skills skills = new Skills();
}
```

And finally my custom editor:

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(SoldierData))]
public class SoldierEditor : Editor
{
    private SerializedProperty life, autoAttack, skills/*, weapon*/;
    private bool showBaseProperties = true, showWeaponProperties = false;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        life = serializedObject.FindProperty("life");
        autoAttack = serializedObject.FindProperty("autoAttack");
        skills = serializedObject.FindProperty("skills");
        //weapon = serializedObject.FindProperty("weapon");
    }
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        showBaseProperties = EditorGUILayout.Foldout(showBaseProperties, "Basic settings:");
        if (showBaseProperties)
        {
            base.OnInspectorGUI();
        }
        serializedObject.Update();
        showWeaponProperties = EditorGUILayout.Foldout(showWeaponProperties, "Weapon settings");
        if (showWeaponProperties)
        {
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(autoAttack);
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(life);
        }
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(skills);
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

uncomment weapon
add: put SoldierEditor in folder named "Editor"

Comment: I got the same results....

is there another difference except the byte[] m_Arr;?

Comment: oh, excuse me, I framed it. You can substitute any serializable values there. The main thing is that the field would be public, I also corrected "SoldierEditor: Editor" and placed this script in a folder called "Editor" I will add that if you want to see the Weapon class in the inspector, then you also need to make it serializable.

Comment: if using [`[SerializeField]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html) the field doesn't have to be `public`. Or the other way round: if a field is `public` it is serialized anyway and doesn't need `[SerializeField]`

Comment: @derHugo  yes,([SerializeField] whith public) it's redundancy. [link](https://answers.unity.com/questions/549814/using-serializefield-vs-public.html)